# Need to animate word with fadeinDown and fadeOutDown effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I need to change a word every 5 seconds with fadeInDown and fadeOutDown effects in Javascript.
I have a set of different words to be displayed. I have used following link for animation, but when the word changes it doesn't have the animation effect.

Animation: http://jschr.github.io/textillate/

ii. For In Animation, select ‘fadeInDown’ + ‘sync’
iii. For Out Animation, select ‘fadeOutDown’ + ’sync

For changing words I have used following code

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var messages = [],
        index = 0;

    messages.push('awesome');
    messages.push('incredible');
    messages.push('cool');
    messages.push('fantastic');

    function cycle() {
        $('#some-id').html(messages[index]);
        index++;

        if (index === messages.length) {
            index = 0;
        }

        setTimeout(cycle, 5000);
    }

    cycle();
});
</script>

HTML code :

<div>
This is so<span id="some-id">awesome</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your question how to add jquery fade or how to add this textillate library's animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Textillate` won't work properly here after animating the first word because your `cycle` javascript function is simply replacing the inner html of the span with the word you want. For `textillate` to work on a list of words, we need to create the appropriate html markup and then append it to desired span element.

**JQUERY**

```
$(function () {
    var messages = [],
    index = 0;

    messages.push('awesome');
    messages.push('incredible');
    messages.push('cool');
    messages.push('fantastic');

    //Function for generating appropriate html markup as required by textillate
    function generateMarkup() {
        var markup = '';

        //Wrapping all words in <li> tags as required by textillate
        messages.forEach(function(item){
            markup += '<li>' + item + '</li>';
        });

        //Wrapping the li tags in <ul class="texts"> tag as required by textillate
        markup = '<ul class="texts">' + markup + '</ul>';
        return markup;
    }
    markup = generateMarkup();

    //Appending the html markup we generated to the desired span element
    $("#some-id").append(markup);

    //Initializing textillate
    $('#some-id').textillate({
        in: {
            effect: 'fadeInDown',
            sync: true,
        },
        out: {
            effect: 'fadeOutDown',
            sync: true,
        },
        loop: true,
        minDisplayTime: 5000, //Delay between changing words
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    This is so <span id="some-id"></span>
</div>
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shikhar/zz6ge3cc/)